# Firefox body margin bug?

Tags: html, css, firefox, margin

I have this simple example:

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li class="clear"></li>
    </ul>
</header>
<section>section</section>
```

And this piece of css:

```
BODY, HTML{
    margin: 0;
}
header{
    margin-bottom: 100px; /* section goes down */
}
UL{
    list-style-type: none;
}
UL LI{
    float: left;
    background: green;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
section{
    background: red;
}
```

So expect for the "header" to go straight to top-left corner, then 100px margin, then "section". In all major browsers that works as expected, but in Firefox (version 16) "header" get extra margin-top for some reason.

Is this a bug?

Here is an jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/AvZek/2/

BTW
If I use clearfix instead of the "clear" class then it’s working just fine.

Comment: I am not looking for workarounds, I am interested whenever this is a bug, or just behaviour that I don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is, without a doubt, a bug. The margin is definitely not supposed to be there.

- According to Firebug, the only non-zero margin that is computed that I can see is the same `margin-bottom: 100px` on your `header` element as in your CSS. Everything else is zero.
- Even Firebug's DOM inspector has trouble identifying it; it never highlights that region, with the obvious exception of when you're inspecting `html` itself (which it highlights as part of its content area).

I found tons of bug reports which were closed as duplicates of [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451791), with numerous more test cases. Plus, it looks like it has been around since at least Firefox 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That is exactly what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of polluting your code with non-semantic and unnecessary empty `<li>`-s just add `overflow: hidden` to your `<ul>`

***HTML***

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</header>
<section>section</section>
```

***CSS***

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AvZek/3/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `{padding-bottom:100px;}` instead of margin to achieve this ..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to avoid this issue. I am interested whenever this is a bug, or just behaviour that I don't understand.