# Random padding/margin at top of webpage only on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

Can anyone figure this out? take a look at what I mean here:

https://www.wellchild.org.uk/

Compare it between any other browser & FireFox

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Have tested this on windows & mac in IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera & FireFox.. and its on FireFox im getting this problem!

Ive tried inspecting the page with the dev tools available in firefox and cant figure it out

Comment: Would you add relevant code to the question?

Comment: I think this is the same problem and it looks like a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070630/firefox-body-margin-bug

Comment: @Pavlo, there is a link to the code in the question

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 3):

Try one of the following:

1) remove 
float: left;
from .mainHead nav ul li (style.css ... line 78)
That should fix the problem cross-browsers. You may have to define left/right margin.

2)add the following code to style.css which will target only firefox browser:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .mainHead nav ul li{
    float:none;
   }
}
```

Let me know what works for you...

Comment: Sadly this didnt work for me, though I found that Piro's answer did however fix my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but it might be linked to this Firefox Bug :
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=451791

In your case, this simple css workaround seems to get your page fixed on FF (haven't testedif it breaks other navigators)

```
.container { padding: 0.001em; }
```