# How to cope with chrome/firefox margin-collapsing <details>/<summary> differently?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, margin

Gaze upon this example HTML/CSS, and observe how Chrome (v110) and Firefox (v108) render them differently.

```css
* {border:0; margin:0; padding:0; vertical-align:baseline;}
details {margin:0;}
details summary {margin: 1em 0 1em 1em;}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>First</summary>
</details> 
<details>
  <summary>Second</summary>
</details>
```

The first [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) tag is notably empty except for its [`<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary).
As best I can figure, Chrome is deciding to [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) the bottom margin of the first `<summary>` with the top margin of the second `<summary>` *only when the `<details>` is open*, whereas Firefox collapses them in either case. I'm building a semantic "template", so I'd like to know how to write the CSS to be Firefox/Chrome agnostic. I want:

- The opening/closing of `<details>` that are empty except for their `<summary>` to not affect the spacing/margins at all.
- Consistent margins between open, empty `<details>` and closed `<details>`.

How do you write CSS that will render the HTML consistently?

---

Researching this browser discrepancy, it appears Firefox is the one out of compliance with the W3 standards. See this potentially related [CSS margin test](http://test.csswg.org/suites/css21_dev/20101027/html4/margin-collapse-157.htm). Collected potentially relevant reading here:

- [SO: Do vertical margins collapse reliably and consistently across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28175257/2671341)
- [SO: Cross-browser Issue: Min-height and collapsing margins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24013878/2671341)
- [SO: Firefox body margin bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13070630/2671341)
- [Chromium "Issue" 321295](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321295)

Answer (score 1):

Differences in Firefox/Chrome aside, there's a way to avoid this issue altogether.

#### Declare *no margins* in `<summary>`; instead put them in `<details>`.

```css
details {margin: 1em 0 1em 1em;}
details summary {margin:0;}
```

This makes sense, because `<details>` is the "block" element here, and should be handling the margins relative to any other block elements in your HTML. The `<summary>` tag has default value `display:list-item;`—it's really just intended to contain some text or something to click to expand the details.